# odoo module details by navigation url

Tags: odoo

I am very new to odoo. I want to know is there a way which can tell which module is currently loaded in the page clicked.

For example: my local environment is

```
localhost:8069/web#page=0&view_type=list&model=stock.picking.type&menu_id=167&action=176
```

So when i click on Main Menu Item ( Warehouse) i see above url. with side bar and kanban view in middle.

Is there a way to know which module is currently this one, so that i can look into view file for other links on sidebar. Moreover any idea about menu_id and action.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can determine the module that's currently loaded but from the url there's a lot you can determine when we inspect the url closely

`view_type=list&model=stock.picking.type&menu_id=167&action=176

`view_type=list`

Describes the type of view that's currently loaded in the browser, there are different types of views in odoo: list view(tree), form, kanban, Graph etc read more about it here https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/views.html

`model=stock.picking.type`

The model that's currently loaded (this is probably what you're looking for and gives you a clue on what module is currently loaded, from here we can easily guess that it's the stock module that's currently loaded....stock.picking.type is a model under the stock module)

`menu_id=167&action=176`

That is the menu_id and the action id of the current view

Actions and menus are regular records in database, usually declared through data files (XML), you can read more about it here

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html#actions-and-menus

You can also activate the developer mode in odoo and hover over a field to see the object(model) that field is related to

What i personally do if i can't find a module through a model name is to use grep to search the addons folder like this. for example in your case

`grep stock.picking.type addons -r`

will return entries of all files(and their path) containing `stock.picking.type`

Comment: Thanks danidee for this tutorial.